# Where's the memory leak in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, ios

It's a simple app that takes 30 pics from my Resources folder, puts them into an `NSMutableArray` during `viewDidLoad`, and then changes the pic based on accelerometer data.  I have a `UIImageView` from IB covering the whole view, and when the accelerometer updates its info, it swaps the `uiimageview.image` to a diff pic.  Works for about 10 seconds, and then crashes with this:

```
Program received signal:  “0”.
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")
```

After looking around on here it sounds like it's a memory leak.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
Interface:
{
    UIAccelerometer *accel;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *pic;
    NSMutableArray *picArr;
}

Implementation:

- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
[super viewDidLoad];

picArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  //array of pics to be used
NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] init]; //dynamic path of images to save to array

for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
{
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"nativity_test_%i", i] ofType:@"jpg"];

    [picArr addObject:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]];

}

accel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
accel.delegate = self;
accel.updateInterval = 0.5f;

[path release];

pic.image = [picArr objectAtIndex:15];
}

- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{

if(acceleration.y < 0.0f) //goes thru the tilted left pics
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
    {                       
        if( acceleration.y >= (-(15.0f-(double)i)/30.0f) && acceleration.y <  (-(14.0f-(double)i)/30.0f) )
        {
            pic.image = [picArr objectAtIndex:i+1];
        }
    }
}

else if(acceleration.y > 0.0f) //goes thru tilted right pics
{       
    for (int i = 1; i <= 14; i++)
        if( acceleration.y > ((double)i/30.0f) && acceleration.y <= ((double)(i+1)/30.0f) )
        {
            pic.image = [picArr objectAtIndex:i+15];
        }
}
}
```

Please let me know if I left out any pertinent info.

Comment: Does it matter that the instance variables aren't properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a crash caused by a memory leak, but by an overrelease of memory. Your crash is caused by this line:

```
[path release];
```

Remove that line and you should be fine. For some values of fine, anyway; most of what George says also applies.

The reason is that the path being released will be this one:

```
path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"nativity_test_%i", i] ofType:@"jpg"];
```

That's an object with an effective retain count of zero. While it has a positive retain count, it's already been autoreleased and will be released when you return to the main event loop.

You should also remove this line:

```
NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] init]; //dynamic path of images to save to array
```

The reason is you're assigning the result of pathForResource to path, never actually using it. You'll need to declare path as a variable, of course. I suggest changing the pathForResource line to this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"nativity_test_%i", i] ofType:@"jpg"];
```

This is a smart change, as there's no reason you'd need this outside of the loop.

You should also fix this line:

```
[picArr addObject:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]];
```

[UIImage alloc] returns an UIImage with an effective retain count of 1. Adding it to an array will increase that to two. If you're just releasing the array later, this will cause a memory leak. Instead:

```
[picArr addObject:[[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]] autorelease];
```

That will mean you're adding an UIImage with an effective retain count of 0 to the array, which will bump it to 1, making the array the only owner of the object. Later when the array goes away, so will most of the images. (The imageView will also own whichever is assigned to it.)

Don't be frustrated by this stuff: one day soon you'll just suddenly get it and wonder why it ever caused you headaches. :)

Comment: Well I no longer get memory warnings, but it still crashes.  Made all the changes you said.  Stumped.  Might just put in 30 different uiimageview's and and them show/hide.  Sloppy, yes.

Comment: Try turning on NSZombieEnabled, that should help you find this. I think this is the right approach, and it should be fixable.

Comment: Okay for some reason it works fine on a 3rd gen iPod, but not my iPhone 3G.  Both running 4.1.  Any idea why?

Comment: Well, your iPhone 3G is going to have less RAM. How large are your images?

Comment: Yeah I found that out lol.  Didn't think the pics were too big, but guess they were.  About 440kb * 30 images = 13.2 mb.  Didn't think that was too much...

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of problems here:

**1)** You aren't releasing the UIImage objects you're adding to "picArr".

This line:

```
[picArr addObject:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]];
```

Should be something like this instead:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
[picArr addObject: image];
[image release];
```

I believe you could also do:

```
[picArr addObject: [[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] autorelease]];
```

**2)** You don't need to do NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] init];  You can just do:
    NSString *path;
You are giving the path variable a value inside that first loop so there's no need to alloc+init.  Once you change this you can get rid of this line:

```
[path release];
```

**3)** I don't see where you are releasing "picArr" itself, you'll need to.  You may be doing it already but didn't include that bit of code in your post.

Comment: I actually already had it with 

    [picArr addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];

but that didn't work either.  I tried what you said that didn't work either.  picArr gets released in dealloc, but I use it for the life of the program so I don't want to release it during execution.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: [picArr addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]] should be fine.  I believe the [path release]; line will cause problems.  Try my #2 in the answer I provided...just use NSString *path; and stop releasing "path"

Comment: I get memory warnings 1 and 2 before it crashes too.  I assumed it wasn't in viewDidLoad since it makes it fine until it swaps enough pics out.  I ran Instruments (first time using it), and it seemed like every time the pic changed more memory was taken.  I thought

 pic.image = [picArr objectAtIndex:i+1] 

just told the image property in "pic" to point to the image object in the array.  I dunno.

Comment: Are we seeing your entire interface + implementation in your question?  Without 100% of the code we may not be seeing everything that could be causing the problem.